# search a set of values in other set of values for a row

Tags: mysql

Hello I am having issues with execution time on a query that searches for users ( from users table ) that are having at least one interest from one specified interests set and a location from a specified locations set. So I have this test DB:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `interests` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `interests`
    --

    INSERT INTO `interests` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'auto'),
    (2, 'moto'),
    (3, 'health'),
    (4, 'garden'),
    (5, 'house'),
    (6, 'music'),
    (7, 'video'),
    (8, 'games'),
    (9, 'it');

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `locations`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locations` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `locations`
    --

    INSERT INTO `locations` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'engalnd'),
    (2, 'austia'),
    (3, 'germany'),
    (4, 'france'),
    (5, 'belgium'),
    (6, 'italy'),
    (7, 'russia'),
    (8, 'poland'),
    (9, 'norway'),
    (10, 'romania');

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `users`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `users`
    --

    INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`) VALUES
    (1, 'email1@test.com'),
    (2, 'email2@test.com'),
    (3, 'email3@test.com'),
    (4, 'email4@test.com'),
    (5, 'email5@test.com'),
    (6, 'email6@test.com'),
    (7, 'email7@test.com'),
    (8, 'email8@test.com'),
    (9, 'email9@test.com'),
    (10, 'email10@test.com');

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `users_interests`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_interests` (
      `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `interest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`interest_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `users_interests`
    --

    INSERT INTO `users_interests` (`user_id`, `interest_id`) VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 5),
    (2, 7),
    (2, 8),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 1),
    (4, 5),
    (4, 6),
    (4, 7),
    (4, 8),
    (5, 1),
    (5, 2),
    (5, 8),
    (6, 3),
    (6, 7),
    (6, 8),
    (7, 7),
    (7, 9),
    (8, 5);

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `users_locations`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_locations` (
      `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`location_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `users_locations`
    --

    INSERT INTO `users_locations` (`user_id`, `location_id`) VALUES
    (2, 5),
    (2, 7),
    (2, 8),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 1),
    (4, 5),
    (4, 6),
    (4, 7),
    (4, 8),
    (5, 1),
    (5, 2),
    (5, 8),
    (6, 3),
    (6, 7),
    (6, 8),
    (7, 7),
    (7, 9),
    (8, 5);
```

Is there a better way to query it than this:

```
SELECT email, 
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT ui.interest_id ) AS interests, 
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT ul.location_id ) AS locations
FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN users_interests ui ON u.id = ui.user_id
LEFT JOIN users_locations ul ON u.id = ul.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING IF( interests IS NOT NULL , FIND_IN_SET( 2, interests )
OR FIND_IN_SET( 3, interests ) , 1 )
AND IF( locations IS NOT NULL , FIND_IN_SET( 2, locations )
OR FIND_IN_SET( 3, locations ) , 1 )
```

This is the best solution I found but it still slow on a 500k and 1mil rows in the relational tables ( locations and interests ). Especially when you are matching against a large set of values ( let's say above 50 locations and interests ).

So I am trying to achieve the result this query produces, but a bit faster:

```
email               interests        locations

email1@test.com     1,2             [BLOB - 0B]
email5@test.com     1,2,8           1,2,8
email6@test.com     3,7,8           3,7,8
email9@test.com     [BLOB - 0B]     [BLOB - 0B]
email10@test.com    [BLOB - 0B]     [BLOB - 0B]
```

I also tried to join against an SELECT UNION table - for the matching set - but it was even slower. Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN users_interests ui ON u.id = ui.user_id
LEFT JOIN users_locations ul ON u.id = ul.user_id

LEFT JOIN (SELECT 2 as interest UNION SELECT 3 as interest) as `is` ON ui.interest_id = is.interest
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 2 as location UNION SELECT 3 as location ) as `ls` ON ul.location_id = ls.location

WHERE IF(ui.user_id IS NOT NULL, `is`.interest IS NOT NULL,1) AND
 IF(ul.user_id IS NOT NULL, ls.location IS NOT NULL,1) 

GROUP BY u.id
```

I am using this for a basic targeting system.
I would appreciate very much, any suggestion! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you have `IS` is reserved word for mysql

and also your `group by` can slow your query but i dont see any meaning to use `group by u.id` here since the `u.id` is already `unique id`.

[**look demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/439d9/8)

try use backticks around it.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM `users` u
 LEFT JOIN users_interests ui ON u.id = ui.user_id
 LEFT JOIN users_locations ul ON u.id = ul.user_id

 LEFT JOIN (SELECT 2 as interest UNION SELECT 3 as interest) as `is` 
     ON ui.interest_id = `is`.interest
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT 2 as location UNION SELECT 3 as location ) as `ls` 
     ON ul.location_id = `ls`.location


WHERE IF(ui.user_id IS NOT NULL, `is`.interest IS NOT NULL,1) 
 AND
 IF(ul.user_id IS NOT NULL, `ls`.location IS NOT NULL,1)
```